# Kotlin Gradle Plugin issue

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':keyboard_utils' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

I have upgraded Android studio, flutter, kotlin and then I am getting this error.

Comment: ```keyboard_utils``` package have been discontinued try different package or download the ```keyboard_utils``` repo from github upgrade there android folder and then include this package locally in your projects ```pubspec.yaml``` file. I have used many discontinued flutter packages like this.
Note: after upgrade package may not work so you have to fix it

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, I have updated my Ext.kotlin_version 1.8.10 and also  changed the version "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'"
then opened the Android in seperate window and executed.